# How to add multiple UITextFields to a UIAlertView in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to add Multiple UITextField on a UIAlertView in iOS 7?

```
 myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Your Detail" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Register",nil];
txtEmail = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 220, 25)];
txtEmail.placeholder = @"email address";
txtFirstName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 70, 220, 25)];
txtFirstName.placeholder = @"first Name";
txtSurname = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 220, 25)];
txtSurname.placeholder = @"surname";
[myAlertView addSubview:txtEmail];
[myAlertView addSubview:txtFirstName];
[myAlertView addSubview:txtSurname];

[myAlertView show];
```

in IOS 6 no problem but in IOS 7 it not show UITextField

Comment: Just working as charm http://stackoverflow.com/a/25175989/2459296

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this any more, there is no `addSubview` for `UIAlertView` any more in iOS7.

Below are good alternative:

[ios-custom-alertview](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)

[MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, you need to use alternative check the url's in my question, this is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative in your case is to set 
`alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;`

This will add a text field for you. You can access it in the UIAlertView delegate callback by using `UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ios7, you need to set,

```
myAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `addSubview` on `UIAlertView` in iOS7.
That's why it is not working, as an alternative you can use a custom view for doing this.
Create a custom view and add textfield to it and add animations for this.

You can find customized alertview's on this link: [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alertview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" message:@"Please enter the email ID associated with your Hngre account." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Here you go" otherButtonTitles:@"No, thanks", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].secureTextEntry = NO; //Will disable secure text entry for second textfield.
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"First Placeholder"; //Will replace "Username"
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].placeholder = @"Second Placeholder"; //Will replace "Password"
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [MZFormSheetPresentationController](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MZFormSheetPresentationController) by m1entus.

He provides a number of examples on GitHub and CocoaPods and they're ready to use.